# Joining 2 Tables with Non-Unique Values - Comparing Legacy to Current Data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am looking to compare some transaction data from our legacy system with the current system. This is being used as a means for comparison. The problem is that certain transactions are listed multiple times, often due to needing to report it in all the corresponding reporting agencies.

So let me just give a quick Example:

Current System Transaction Data

```
Transaction#| ReportCode |
:---------- | ---------: |
 123        | 3          |
 123        | 4          |
 1234       | 3          |
 1235       | 4          |
 1255       | 6          |
```

Legacy System Transaction Data

```
Transaction#| ReportCode |
:---------- | ---------: |
 123        | 3          |
 123        | 4          |
 1234       | 6          |
 1235       | 6          |
```

I am trying to make a query that would result in the following based on comparing the two systems:

```
Transaction#| ReportCode |
:---------- | ---------: |
 123        | 3          |  Match with Legacy
 123        | 4          |  Match with Legacy
 1234       | 3          |  MisMatch Legacy Reports 6
 1235       | 4          |  Mismatch Legacy Reports 6
 1255       | 6          |  Not in Legacy System
```

So the main problem I am having is when the same transaction is reported on multiple schedules. Since it is a JOIN, it simply grabs whichever first Reportcode that it sees, so I will often see results like this:

```
Transaction#| ReportCode |
:---------- | ---------: |
 123        | 3          |  MisMatch Legacy Reports 4
 123        | 4          |  MisMatch Legacy Reports 3
```

Does anyone know of a good way around this issue I am experiencing? Below is my current code

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
                     a.ReportCode AS LegacyReportCode b.ReportCode AS CurrentReportCode CASE WHEN a.Reportcode= b.ReportCode THEN 'ReportCode Matched' WHEN a.ReportCode IS NULL 
                     THEN 'In Current not in Legacy' WHEN b.ReportCode IS NULL THEN 'In Legacy not in Current' ELSE 'Mismatch' END AS ReportCodeMatchResult, a.TransactionID AS LegacyTransactionID,
                     b.TransactionID AS CurrentTransactionID

FROM                dbo.LegacySystem AS a FULL OUTER JOIN
                     dbo.CurrentSystem AS b ON a.TransactionID = b.TransactionID
```

Comment: Of course sql-server is going to pick up a random first one, because your join is only on a trasaction number.  You need to join on both the transaction number and the reportcode otherwise how do you think sql will know which transaction number you meant?

Comment: Right, I understand that - But given the situation my question is more of a what is the best workaround type of question?

Answer (score 0):

First, I would get all the ones that do match by joining CurrentSystem to LegacySystem on both TransactionID AND ReportCode. Then, write a separate query to get the ones that do not match

```
Select c.TransactionNum, c.ReportCode, (Select top 1 ReportCode From Legacy Where TransactionNum = c.TransactionNum) as mismatch
From Current c
Where Not Exists
(
    Select 1 From Legacy l
    Where c.TransactionNum = l.TransactionNum and c.ReportCode = l.ReportCode
)
```

You can UNION ALL them together if you need them in one result set.

Answer (score 0):

`FULL OUTER JOIN` is pretty much the right way to go.  However, you can't really specify the `ReportCode` that doesn't match.

However, you can get the information you want by including `ReportCode` in the `ON` conditions:

```
SELECT a.ReportCode AS LegacyReportCode b.ReportCode AS CurrentReportCode,
       (CASE WHEN a.Reportcode = b.ReportCode THEN 'ReportCode Matched'
             WHEN a.ReportCode IS NULL THEN 'In Current not in Legacy'
             WHEN b.ReportCode IS NULL THEN 'In Legacy not in Current'
             ELSE 'Mismatch'
        END) AS ReportCodeMatchResult,
       a.TransactionID AS LegacyTransactionID,
       b.TransactionID AS CurrentTransactionID
FROM dbo.LegacySystem a FULL OUTER JOIN
     dbo.CurrentSystem b
     ON a.TransactionID = b.TransactionID AND a.ReportCode = b.ReportCode;
```